# Filetered aggregation query ouput needed in non-nested format

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following query which gives the desired output, but in nested format.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Pre_Post": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "PRE": {
            "range": {
              "mydate": {
                "gte": "2017-12-31||-6M",
                "lte": "2017-12-31"
              }
            }
          },
          "POST": {
            "range": {
              "mydate": {
                "gte": "2018-08-01",
                "lte": "2018-08-07"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dimension1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "myType.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sales": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "sales"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output of above is roughly in format

```
"PRE_POST": {
    "PRE": {
        "buckets": {
            "dimension1": {
                "key": "field1",
                "buckets": {
                    "sales": 50
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this in non-nested format something like the one given by composite query, with some less nested-ness.

desired sample output something like

```
"PRE_POST": {
    "Key1": "PRE",
    "dimension1": "field1",
    "buckets": {
        "sales": 50
    }
}
```

I have tried composite, but composite do not allow filters. 
I have tried composite with PRE_POST as script field, but i.e. very slow. 
I have also tried adjacency matrix, where two filters are for PRE and POST and others are for each dimension1 field. But this returns too much of unnecessary data.

Is there any way or any method I am missing to get the output in less nested format.

Comment: Currently I'm not aware of any possibility. Transforming the response will need to happen at the caller-side.

Comment: Thanks @f.loris. I cam to same conclusion.